# In Minecraft multiplayer, do I keep my inventory after signing out?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing on a multiplayer server in Minecraft. When I sign out of the server and close the game, do I need to have all my items stored in chests, or will items in my inventory and armor I'm wearing still be there the next time I sign in to the same server? Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inventory saving was added a few months back so providing the server has been updated since then, and there's no additional addons that are programmed to prevent this, then yes - your inventory should be untouched when you next login.

Comment: Inventory saving on logout has been in Survival Multiplayer since it started. What was added recently was server-side storage of inventory during play, to fix infinite tools and other client-side inventory hacks.

Comment: Unless the server operator deletes your playerfile, that is. :)

Answer (score 9):

They will still be there when you log back in.